# Is defining auxiliary functions outside of an object allowed?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have a class and a given quite complicated method for the sake of which I've defined some auxiliary functions, which aren't however used anywhere else. Now I'm wondering whether I should

- add them to my class - it seems to be what it should be done according to the OOP paradigm
- keep them outside, i.e. separately, only in my implementation file - since filling up my class definition with that sort of semi-redundant methods would make my class definition less readable.

My question is what should I do when C++ style is concerned. I feel that the second solution goes against the OOP principles, though C++ isn't an object-oriented language but a hybrid one. The functions I mention, if implemented as class methods, would be static.

Comment: The OOP paradigm is not nonsensical. Your first option may be what silly fanatic people may tell you should be done, but I would not consider being nonsensical a good idea.

Comment: See this article: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put them in an **[Unnamed namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yct4x9k5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** inside your source file.
The unnamed namespace allows your functions to be visible within the translation unit, but not outside the translation unit. Your functions still have an external linkage but they are simply invisible to anyone outside the translation unit.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I'm going to add this: the answers given so far are fine, but since C++11 I found that for strictly auxiliary functions there is a better and less intrusive solution:

Define them as lambdas inside the method they serve.

This will make them invisible everywhere else and give them proper access permissions without requiring the use of a `friend` declaration or making them private static members.